# ngrx - conditionally stop/remove Effect/Action

Tags: angular, redux, ionic2, rxjs, ngrx

I am currently building an application with Ionic2 and ngrx and I am trying to stop certian Actions if there is no network connection.

With stop I mean to somehow make them invisible for other Effects and the store or stop them from further "propagating".

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
@Effect()
checkNetworkConnection$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(book.ActionTypes.LOAD_BOOKS, book.ActionTypes.CREATE_BOOK)
  .if(Network.connection === 'none')
  .do(() => new ShowNetworkAlertAction()) //Returns ShowNetworkAlertAction
  .stopPropagation(); // Removes the Action from the stream
```

`stopPropagation()` should somehow "remove" the Action from the stream, after that it should be like if the action has never been dispatched. Even the store should not change anything or execute the code that would be executed on this Action.

Comment: you mean like, [`filter`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter)?

Comment: @paulpdaniels no, I want something that does something if an Action is dispatched and then removes this Action from the stream (no other effects or reducer should react to this Action)

Comment: My understanding is that effects receive actions that have *already* been dispatched to the store, so you cannot use an effect to stop the propagation of the `LOAD_BOOKS` and `CREATE_BOOK` actions when there is no network connectivity. Effects are sources of actions; they are not action filters.

Comment: @cartant Ok thanks, I missunderstood Effects... Where should I intercept the actions?

Comment: The only way that I can see how this could be done would be to dispatch the actions to something that intercepts/filters and then dispatches to the store. However, intercepting and swallowing the actions isn't something that I'd be inclined to do. Instead, I'd use an effect that emits a connectivity change action that sees the connectivity status represented in the state and I'd use that state to either enable/disable the UI to prevent actions from being emitted in the first place (when there is no connectivity) or to fail fast in the HTTP-related effects, etc. - but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

One solution would be to add network online/offline to the state (or have it otherwise available as an observable stream). Then you could use `takeUntil` in your effects that need to ignore actions when you're offline.

In the spirit of the example above, you could try something like this (untested, but should be close):

```js
// NOTE: This effect listens for `LOAD_BOOKS` command actions, and emits the
// `PROGRESS` and either `LOAD_BOOKS_SUCCESS` or `LOAD_BOOKS_FAILURE` event actions 
// that the reducers will listen for.
@Effect()
loadBooksWhenOnline$ = this.actions$
    .ofType('LOAD_BOOKS')
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
    .filter(([payload, state]) => state.network.status === 'online')
    .switchMap(([payload, state]) => {
        const networkOffline$ = this.actions$.ofType('NETWORK')
            .filter(action => action.payload === 'offline');

        const someOtherReasonToCancel$ = this.actions$.ofType('CANCEL');

        const stop$ = Observable.merge(networkOffline$, someOtherReasonToCancel$);

        return Observable.concat(
            Observable.of({ type: 'PROGRESS', payload: { isLoading: true } }),
            this.bookService.getBooks$(payload)
                .map(books => ({ type: 'LOAD_BOOKS_SUCCESS', payload: books }))
                .catch(err => Observable.of({ type: 'LOAD_BOOKS_FAILURE', payload: { payload, err })
                .takeUntil(stop$),
            Observable.of({ type: 'PROGRESS', payload: { isLoading: false } }),
        );
    })
    .observeOn(async); // may want this, depending on how your actions interact

// elsewhere in reducerville
export function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOAD_BOOKS_SUCCESS':
            return reduceLoadBooksSuccessAction(state, action);
        case 'LOAD_BOOKS_FAILURE':
            return reduceLoadBooksFailureAction(state, action);
        case 'PROGRESS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                progress: Object.assign({}, state.progress, action.payload)
            });
        // ...
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

There's an initial filter check with the state just to make sure you're actually online, and then going offline later happens via `takeUntil`. I also added an additional CANCEL action just to show how to stop the effect for multiple reasons.

Also, the above example assumes a model where effects handle 'request' actions (i.e. commands) and the reducers are pure functions that handle the 'result' actions (i.e. events).

UPDATE 2: Ok, I added a simple `isLoading` progress flag with a corresponding reducer, as requested. Specifically, the addition of the `Observable.concat` call wraps the book service query with `isLoading` state changes. The progress action could also have other progress flags as well, and this example only updates the `isLoading` property.

Comment: Looks good! But is the `LOAD_BOOKS` action still going into reducers? It would be a problem because this action could make the change state and set for example a `{loading:true}` flag which will not be set back to false

Comment: Sorry, I should've shown wrapping the results of the book service to emit the events that the reducers are watching. The idea is that the effect listens for the request, but the reducers only listen for the result of the request. I'll try to update it.

Comment: @Daskus I added some simple success/failure events mapped from the book service observable, along with corresponding sample reducer code. Let me know if that clears it up. The main idea of this kind of async setup is the distinction between effects (side-effects) and reducers (pure functions).

Comment: Ok but what if I want to set a loading flag in the reducer? Would I need to have two actions? `LOAD_BOOKS_WHEN_ONLINE` and  `LOAD_BOOKS`. This implies also two effects: one which triggers on `LOAD_BOOKS_WHEN_ONLINE` and returns `LOAD_BOOKS` if there is network connectivity and another one which calls the http-service. In my opinion this would be to much boilderplate for simply checking if the user is online. Or is this not needed?

Comment: @Daskus I added a simple `PROGRESS` action that shows how to bookend the book service call with `isLoading` flag changes for showing a spinner or something. In this simplistic example, the LOAD_BOOKS command will just be ignored (or canceled) when offline. However, in a real app, you may want to do something else probably leveraging the network status flag (this is just meant to show some strategies for conditionals in effects involving async calls.)  You'll have to customize and expand things for your particular app, of course, but hopefully some ideas here will get you started!

Comment: I had misread your previous comment, but I just noticed the "returns `LOAD_BOOKS`" part. This effect listens for `LOAD_BOOKS` but doesn't return it. It returns either `LOAD_BOOKS_SUCCESS` or `LOAD_BOOKS_FAILURE`. I'll update it with action literals instead of placeholder action constructor calls to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will try it out

Comment: @rob3c I'm interested in the `.observeOn(async)` at the end of the effect. Do you have any links to documentation on that, I'm struggling to find any.

Comment: @MattSugden `observeOn` isn't ngrx-specific, it's just a regular part of the rxjs library. `async` indicates which scheduler to use. I mentioned in the comment that it's optional, because sometimes immediate synchronous evaluation in some actions can throw things off (ngrx is working on this, and may be fixed by now). Good search keywords to understand it better are `rxjs` `observeOn`, `schedulers` and `async`. If you still need help, I recommend asking a new question here tagged with `rxjs`, as it isn't ngrx-specific.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find is https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/docs/api.md#utilities. Have you had a look at the unsubscribe stuff.

Edit:

Hey a made a small service that seems to stop all ngrx effects stuff. You would just have to call the method when your app goes offline. Have not really tested it but when I called this in my app it stopped all effects from running. Seems like this is the sort of thing you want to do.

```
import {EffectsSubscription} from "@ngrx/effects"
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core"
@Injectable()
export class EffectsOffline
{
    constructor(private subscription: EffectsSubscription)
    {
    }

    stopPropagation()
    {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but maybe I missed to say that I want to stop also the action itself. Another thing is that I just want to stop certian actions and not all of them since this would break the whole application