# Ngrx cancel dispatched actions after logout action

Tags: redux, ngrx

How can I block all dispatched action that fire after my logout action in ngrx ? is there some sort of root dispatcher that handle this logic ?

Comment: You can't block actions dispatched directly to the store. See the comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40870990/6680611) question.

Comment: I think that he wants to cancel running Effects and not really actions. Maybe like if you dispatch an action `UPDATE_PROFILE` with payload `{newName: 'Some new name'}`, one of your Effects catches it and make an HTTP call to the API. But let say the request it taking a long time and the user clicks on disconnect. If the previous request ends after you've been disconnected it would still update your (cleaned) store.

Comment: @Maxime yes that is exactly the problem I'm facing right now

Answer (score 1):

I'm basing this answer on [Maxime's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455244/ngrx-cancel-dispatched-actions-after-logout-action#comment75938580_44455244), so hopefully I understood your requirements correctly.

I had a similar requirement a few days ago: *prevent any action dispatch from a running effect based on the app-state*.
In addition, I needed something to use this logic in a lot of effects, so it had to be simple to use.

---

My solution was to filter the effect chain once the running request finishes. So any response gets ignored once the user logged out.

First, I created a helper-class which wraps this 'ignore'-logic:

**effect-helper.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AppState } from 'app/reducers/root.reducer';

@Injectable()
export class EffectHelper {
    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { }

    ignoreWhenLoggedOut<T>() {
        return (source): Observable<T> => source
            // get current app state
            .withLatestFrom(this.store, (result, state) => ({ result, state }))
            // only continue when user is logged in
            .filter(combined => combined.state.auth !== undefined)
            // pass on the result of the request when user is logged in
            .map(combined => combined.result);
    };
}
```

The `ignoreWhenLoggedOut` method takes an Observable sequence and filters when the `auth`-slice of the global app-state is `undefined`. (In my case, an undefined auth-state means that no user is logged in).

The helper can now be used in any effect, for example:

**my-effects.ts**

```js
import * as web from 'app/actions/web.action';
import { EffectHelper } from 'app/shared/effects-helper';

@Injectable()
export class MyEffects {

    @Effect() getWebRequest$ = this.actions$
        .ofType(web.WEB_REQUEST)
        .map((action: web.WebRequestAction) => action.input)
        .switchMap(input => this.svc.getWebRequest(input)
            /* 
             * inject the ignore-logic into the effect
             * notice that helper gets typed, so we have typesafety down the chain
             */
            .let(this.effectHelper.ignoreWhenLoggedOut<MyResultType>())
            // this continues only when user is logged in
            .map(result => new web.WebSuccessAction(result))
            .catch(error => {
                return Observable.of(new web.WebFailureAction(error));
            })
        );

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private svc: WebService,
        // inject effect-helper
        private effectHelper: EffectHelper
    ) { }
}
```

As you can see, I can now prevent any running effect from dispatching further actions with a one-liner thanks to the [`let`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/let.md)-operator.

(Don't forget to provide `EffectHelper` in your module, like you do with any other service).